# Power sets question about $\subseteq$ and $\in$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question with regards to this question as follows:

Let $A = \{1,2,\{1,2\}\}$. Determine whether the following statements are true or false with a brief explanation of why.

a) $\{1,2\} \subseteq P(A)$

b) $\{1,2\} \in P(A)$

In this case, I am not sure why $a)$ false since I wrote out $P(A): \{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{\{1,2\}\},\{1,2\},\{1,\{1,2\}\},\{2,\{1,2\}\},\{1,2,\{1,2\}\}\}$

Then is it not the case that $\{1,2\} \subseteq P(A)$ ? I think I need some clarification about the difference of $\subseteq$ and $\in$. I had always thought that if it was listed without braces inside an overall brace of the entire set, then it would be written as $\subseteq$ since I thought of it as "the set containing the set". In this case, I know that $1 \in A$ and $\{1,2\} \subseteq A$ but I am not sure about the first two statements since the solutions stated that statement $a)$ is false while statement $b)$ is false.

Would someone please help me correct my understanding ?

Thank you

Comment: Note that $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}\subseteq P(A)$ though. $\{a,b\}\subseteq P(A)$ only if $a\in P(A)$ and $b\in P(A).$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind the difference between $\{1,2\}$ and $\{\{1,2\}\}$.  These are **not** the same as sets.  The first has two elements, the second has only one element.  Furthermore, $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$ is different from both of these.

If it were true that $\{1,2\}$ were indeed a subset of $P(A)$ that would require both $1$ and $2$ to be elements of $P(A)$, however that is not the case.  You happen to have $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ are elements of $P(A)$, but that is not the same thing as $1$ and $2$ being elements of $P(A)$.  Since $\{1,2\}$ has an element that is not an element of $P(A)$ we see that it is not a subset of $P(A)$.

---

Additional information:

A set is a collection of elements.  To write the set, we may write a pair of braces and each item within those braces are the elements.

E.g. $\{1,2\}$ is the set containing two elements, namely the elements "$1$" and "$2$".

Some times, the elements may be sets themselves.  $\{\{1,2\}\}$ is a set containing one element.  That one element namely being the set described in the previous example.

We say an object is "an element of" a set if it is one of those items which is an element of the set.  For example, in the set $\{1,2\}$ the elements are $1$ and $2$.  $3$ is not an element of $\{1,2\}$.  Neither is $\{1\}$.  $\{1\}$ is not an element of $\{1,2\}$.  To denote this "*is an element of*" relation, we use the symbol "$\in$".  To denote the opposite, we use "$\notin$"

Given two sets, $A$ and $B$, we say the set $A$ is a *subset* of $B$ iff every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$.  Worded a different way, $A$ contains no elements that are not also elements of $B$.  Worded a different way, if we were to pick an arbitrary object, if that object happened to be an element of $A$ it must also be an element of $B$.

Given two sets, $A$ and $B$, we say $A$ is **not** a subset of $B$ iff there exists an element of $A$ which is not an element of $B$.

We denote these as $A\subseteq B$ ($A$ is a subset of $B$) and $A\not\subseteq B$ ($A$ is not a subset of $B$).  (*Side note: some authors use $\subset$ to denote the same thing described here, while others use this specifically to denote being a proper subset, one where it is a subset but not equal*)

---

One additional example which will hopefully clear up final confusion:

$\{1,\{2\}\}$ has **elements** $1$ and $\{2\}$.  It has **subsets** $\emptyset, \{1\},\{\{2\}\},\{1,\{2\}\}$.  It does not have subset $\{2\}$ since $2$ is not an element of $\{1,\{2\}\}$.

In the same way, your example has $\{1,2\}$ is an **element** of $P(A)$ but it is not a subset of $P(A)$.  $\{\{1,2\}\}$ is a subset of $P(A)$ however, but this is not the same thing.

Comment: Okay I seem to understand the condition of the 1 and 2 being elements of $P(A)$, but did i list out the elements of $P(A)$ wrong since I do see $\{1,2\}$ though or is that not to be interpreted as being a subset of $P(A)$ but rather as an element

Comment: @PutsandCalls added additional information.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed explanation ! I used to think I had a pretty good grasp of this concept until this question which confused my understanding. Even though $\{\{1,2\}\}$ is listed in the set of $P(A)$, should I remove my understanding of subsets and follow the definition in which $A \subseteq B$ means that all elements of set $A$ are in set $B$ ? Hence, from this definition point of view, it makes sense because then $P(A)$ does not contain neither a $\{\{1\}\}$ nor a $\{\{2\}\}$ and therefore is not a subset of B. Is this a correct interpretation? Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 5):

Take $B=\{1,2,\{3,4\}\}$

$x\in B$ means $x$ is contained in $B$.   Element $x$ is a member of $B$.

Then: $1,2,\{3,4\}$ are all of the elements of $B$.   So we have: $1\in B\\2\in B\\\{3,4\}\in B$

---

$X\subseteq B$ means $X$ is a subset of $B$.   All elements of set $X$ are elements of set $B$.

$\{\}, \{1\},\{2\}, \{1,2\}, \{\{3,4\}\}, \{1,\{3,4\}\}, \{2,\{3,4\}\},\{1,2,\{3,4\}\}$ are all of the subsets of $B$.   So we have : $\{\}\subseteq B\\ \{1\}\subseteq B\\ \vdots\\\{1,2,\{3,4\}\}\subseteq B\\$

Naturally then $\big\{\{\}, \{1\},\{2\}, \{1,2\}, \{\{3,4\}\}, \{1,\{3,4\}\}, \{2,\{3,4\}\},\{1,2,\{3,4\}\}\big\}$ is the powerset of $B$; that is $\mathcal P(B)$

Then $\{1,2\}\in \mathcal P(B)$ but $\{1,2\}\nsubseteq \mathcal P(B)$.   Can you now see why?

Comment: I am beginning to see it, thank you for the explanation. As a follow up, does that mean that $\{3,4\} \not\subseteq \mathcal P(B)$ in your example since there is no 3, 4 listed in $\mathcal P(B)$ but then could you also provide an example of a subset in $\mathcal P(B)$ (Would $\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\} \subseteq \mathcal P(B)$)

Comment: @PutsandCalls Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you. One more question though as an example just to help solidify my understanding. If I have a quantified statement such as $\forall x \in \mathcal P(N), \forall y \in \mathcal P(R), x \subseteq y$, then to disprove this statement I could take any $x$ such as $x = \{\{1\},\{2\}\} \in \mathcal P(N)$ and $y \in \{\{\frac{1}{2}\},\{0\}\} \in \mathcal P(R)$ then $x \not\subseteq y$. Would this be a fair way to disprove of the quantified statement along with the braces for notation? Thank you for the patience

Comment: @PutsandCalls Yes and no. $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}\subseteq\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$. It's a subset of the powerset, not a member.  You want $\{1,2\}\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$  Likewise $\{\tfrac 1 2, 0\}\in\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ You can then use these as a witness to the contrary.

Comment: The difference: Subsets form part of the set. Elements are individual items in the set.  If a set is a box of balls; when you cut or partition the box into smaller boxes then you have subsets.  When you pick out a ball then you have an element.   (Also remember a set of one thing is not the same as the thing itself.  One ball in a box is a box with a ball in it; it's not just the ball.)

Comment: Ah I understand it now, thank you for the help !